# email send using mailchimp in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mailchimp

i am using mailchimp for sending bulk emails, i successfully subscribe emails using code but cant find a way to send email on subscribed list.
Kindly provide solution using mailchimp in asp.net.

Comment: I dont think you can. The API allows you to subscribe / unsubcribe / edit interests / create lists and campaigns, but don't think it allows you to send. I think you need to create and send a campaign via your mailchimp account

Comment: I tried this but visual studio shows error that campaignSendNowInput isn't any methode
campaignSendNowInput campaignSendNowInput = new campaignSendNowInput(key,CampaignId); campaignSendNow campaignSendNow = new campaignSendNow(campaignSendNowInput); campaignSendNowOutput campaignSendNowOutput = campaignSendNow.Execute();